# AppAuth/OpenID-Connect: Login with username and password possible?

Tags: ios, openid-connect, appauth

I want to implement login via OpenID-Connect in an iOS App. The AppAuth-SDK seems to be the standard way to do so. After downloading some examples I am a little bit confused. All AppAuth examples and tutorials are working with a WebView in which the user enters username and password. I want to make a native login screen where the user has to enter username and password. Is that even possible with AppAuth? I read something about "resource owner password grant" and "client secret". Is that what I need?

If somebody could push me in the right direction, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Have you tried to explore APIs provide by AppAuth ? For example, see how token requests are generated and token responses are handled ?

Answer (score 2):

Think [AppAuth-iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) to be a simple set of classes that helps you to build OAuth/OpenID Connect requests and receive responses. Their samples may contain ones which only use WebView with Authorization Code flow. But if you check docs, you can find their class APIs supporting for password grant.

You can build a [OIDTokenRequest](http://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/docs/latest/interface_o_i_d_token_request.html) with related parameters. Here you can use build in grant type **OIDGrantTypePassword** from [OIDGrantTypes](http://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/docs/latest/_o_i_d_grant_types_8h.html). Simply feed in username password obtained from your login mechanism to **OIDTokenRequest** through additionalParameters. Create the request and obtain the response. I haven't tried this myself, but simply looking at the docs suggests this is the way to go.

Always think about supporting libraries as simple classes that were written to help you. That way things become simple to deal with.

Comment: I tried this and worked as you explained. But when it comes refreshing access token is not working as expected. Also it seems logout isn't supporting